# Xamarin iOS reference in Android project in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I created a cross platform application using Xamarin. I need to call native functions of iOS and Android platform in my project. Here is the code:

```
private static Func<IDownloadFile, string> _downloadPath = new Func<IDownloadFile, string>(file =>
{
    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
    {
        string fileName = (new NSUrl(file.Url, false)).LastPathComponent;
        return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), fileName);
    }
    else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
    {
        string fileName = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(file.Url).Path.Split('/').Last();
        return Path.Combine(Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath, fileName);
    }

    return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "");
});
```

This is the code from notification plugin `https://github.com/thudugala/Plugin.LocalNotification`.

The problem is when I use that code the Mono.Android and Xamarin.iOS references are being added to my shared project in `Dependencies/Assemblies` and then when I try to run application in the release mode there is a reference error - I noticed that in my Android project in bin/Release there is Xamarin.iOS reference but there is no reference in Android project. When I remove that reference from `Dependencies/Assemblies` and comment native calls in my code everything compiles correctly. I am confused because of this. Is my above code correctly or I need to call native functions in another way?

Comment: Is your Xamarin.Forms project using a .Net Standard Library or a Shared Library?

Comment: .net standard is used

Comment: When using .net Standard the approach taken is using an interface that defines the functionality you want to expose then implement in each platform. Then using either Xamarin.Forms `DependencyService` or any other IoC container you can match the Interface with the right Classes.

This post (https://www.codemag.com/Article/1707071/Accessing-Platform-Specific-Functionalities-Using-DependencyService-in-Xamarin.Forms)  shows how to do it. If you don't understand anything come back and I will be more than glad to help you.

Comment: @pinedax your solution works, please give it as answer I will accept it. Also please upvote my question because solution is not an obvious one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using .net Standard the approach taken is using an interface that defines the functionality you want to expose then implement in each platform.

In Shared:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    string GetUrlPath(string fileUrl);
}
```

iOS Implementation:

```
public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public string GetUrlPath(string fileUrl)
    {
       string fileName = (new NSUrl(file.Url, false)).LastPathComponent;
       return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), fileName);             
    }
}
```

Android Implementation:

```
public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public string GetUrlPath(string fileUrl)
    {
        string fileName = (new NSUrl(file.Url, false)).LastPathComponent;
        return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), fileName);
    }
}
```

Then using either Xamarin.Forms `DependencyService` or any other IoC container you can match the Interface with the correct implementation.

In your shared code you will use the Interface and the implementation picked will be transparent.

This [post](https://www.codemag.com/Article/1707071/Accessing-Platform-Specific-Functionalities-Using-DependencyService-in-Xamarin.Forms) shows a very complete example of how to do it.